# Removing every nth element from a list until two elements remain in python3

Tags: python

modeling a game of Russian roulette where the contestants stand in a circle.
-every 7th contestant loses until 2 are left alive.

```
contestants = list(range(1, 51))
dead_men = []
dead_man = 6

while len(contestants) > 2:
    if dead_man > len(contestants):
        dead_man = dead_man - len(contestants)
    loser = contestants.pop(dead_man)
    dead_men.append(loser)
    dead_man += 6
```

This gives me an index error with an index of 9 when my list length is 8

Comment: Where is soldiers defined? Do you mean contestants?

Comment: You might consider reading about the related [Josephus problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem), which goes until there is only one man left - using the same rules you had.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you meant `contestants` instead of `soldiers` everywhere?

If so, then I think you just need:

```
while dead_man >= len(contestants):
```

(`while` rather than `if` in case you need to subtract multiple times, and `>=` rather than just `>` since indexes always need to be less than the length of the list)

You might also use `dead_man %= len(contestants)`. This uses module arithmetic.

My favorite way to do this sort of thing with the modulo trick:

```
contestants = list(range(1, 51))
dead_men = []
dead_man = 6 % len(contestants)

while len(contestants) > 2:
    loser = contestants.pop(dead_man)
    dead_men.append(loser)
    dead_man = (dead_man + 6) % len(contestants)
```

Comment: That certainly helped to iterate through the list even longer. But now I get the index error at 6 while the list is 4.

Comment: Sorry about that, see my edits! Use `while` or just use modulo arithmetic.

Comment: I fixed the variable mix-up. I was reading a friends version (collaborative little project) and I mixed in his variables.

Comment: This implementation won't work with `contestant` having less than 6 (but more than 2) elements. In the first iteration of the loop the index is still out of bounds - modulo is a good idea, but it shouldn't be.on the line where you added it.

Comment: @elias Thanks, added a modulo to the first assignment to `dead_men` to cover the case where it's set to an initial invalid value.

Comment: Wonderful use of modulo. I checked the problem by hand to make sure the numbers match up and it worked like a charm. Thank you very much